# php foreach generating trash

Tags: php, foreach

I have here a quite complicated loop what I would like to modify while is not really working as I expected. The problem is: my if statements else condition is generating trash and I don't really know where the problem comes

[image]

```
<div id="container">
    <?php include 'header.php';
    foreach ($vars as $item):



    if (is_array($item['productItems'])):?>

    <div class="product_box">
        <h4>
            <?php echo $item['title']?>
        </h4>

        <?php foreach($item['productItems'] as $products):?>

        <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>


        <div class="product">

            <div class="image_holder">

                <a href="<?php echo $product['image']['medium'];?>" class="preview">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product['image']['small'];?>"
                    alt="gallery thumbnail" title="" />
                </a>


                <?php foreach($product['trackingLinks'] as $key=>$trackinglink): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $trackinglink[0]['ppc']?>"> <span><?php echo $product['name'];?>
                </span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <h5>
                <?php echo 'Preise:&nbsp;'. $product['price'].' &nbsp;'.$product['currency'];?>
            </h5>
            <span><?php echo 'Versand Kosten:&nbsp;'.$product['shippingCosts'].'&nbsp;EUR';?>
            </span>
            <p>
                <?php echo (substr($product['descriptionLong'], 0,150 )).'<a href="'.$trackinglink[0]['ppc'].'">...mehr</a>';?>
            </p>
            <a class="shopping_button"
                href="<?php echo $trackinglink[0]['ppc']?>">zum Shop</a>



        </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>

        <div class="ajax_bar">

            <select id="ajax_call" size="1" name="Weitere Produkte">
                <option value='50'>Weitere Produkte</option>
                <option value='100'>weitere 100</option>
                <option value='150'>weitere 150</option>
            </select>

        </div>

    </div>

    <?php else: ?>


    <div class="text_box">
        <h2>
            <?php echo $item['title'];?>
        </h2>
        <p>
            <?php echo $item['text'];?>
        </p>


    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>


<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</div>
```

Comment: just a suggestion, why dont you create small small functions for `if else blocks` and `foreach loops` to hae a better clarity for whats happening

Comment: `var_dump($products)` just before the second inner foreach

Comment: Could it not be that `<?php foreach($item['productItems'] as $products):?>` is actually an array of the products, where as beneath that you have another foreach that loops through the `$products` variable. as @NiftyDude has said, var_dump($products) to make sure it is an array to loop.

Comment: $products is an array I have been making an output an it looks as it follows  15 => 
    array
      '@id' => string 'f49cf01010df0ddfb829b0f31ac1a72d' (length=32)
      'name' => string 'Apple iPad 2 32GB + 3G schwarz' (length=30)
      'modified' => string '2012-05-01T06:04:42+02:00' (length=25)
      'program' => 
        array
          '@id' => string '1976' (length=4)
          '$' => string 'Misco DE' (length=8)
      'price' => float 565.25
      'currency' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
      'trackingLinks' => 
        array
          'trackingLink' => 
            array

Comment: It looks like you have an error using your arrays/indexes ... Are the characters the first letters from what you expect? Like "p"rint?

Comment: wow thats a lot of code to figure out for a vague question.. I notice you have this though "<?php endforeach ?>"  do you need a semi colon there?

Comment: Yeah I'm lost as well between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a wild guess here and say that this is because you don't escape your output using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars) or [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities).

If you're not sure what's inside the for-loop, use this nifty construct to debug on page:

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($vars, true)), '</pre>';
```

It also helps to look at the page source instead; this usually gives vital clues as to why your page layout is so messed up.

**Update**

Okay got it! It's because of this:

```
<?php else: ?>
<div class="text_box">
    <h2>
        <?php echo $item['title'];?>
    </h2>
    <p>
        <?php echo $item['text'];?>
    </p>
```

The `$item` is a string here, and `$item['title']` is understood by PHP as `$item[0]` which is the first character of `$item` :)

Comment: Yes I have been doing that. Certainly the loop is the problem: in my page source I got <div class="text_box"><h2>s</h2><p>s</p></div> couple of times repeated

Comment: @lgt it just means the data you're getting is not exactly what you expected, so now you're tasked with tracing down the origins :)